# Using several functions and callbacks in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have this code that loads on document.ready and it checks if the user is logged in or not:

```
//Checking if the user is logged in or not
$(function(){
$.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command : "getUserName"},
    function(result){
        if(result==null){
            $("#divGreeting").html("Hello, guest!");
        }
        else {
            $("#divGreeting").html("Hello, "+result+"!");
            $("#divHeader").html("Hello, "+result+"! <a href='javascript:logout()'>Logout</a>");
        }
    });
```

});

If he's not - it says "Hello, guest"; if he is - it says "Hello, *username*", where username is the `result` in this function. What I need, is to make the username in this part: `$("#divGreeting").html("Hello, "+result+"!");` to be a link, which leads to another page with userID, which I don't have. Like this: `$("#divGreeting").html("Hello, <a href='userpage.html?userid="+HAVE TO GET THE ID HERE+"'>"+result+"</a>!");`

I tried to use this function (it does get the:

```
function getUserID(){
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php",
    {
        command : "getUserID"
    },
    function(result){
        return result;
    });
}
```

and to call it like that: `$("#divGreeting").html("Hello, <a href='userpage.html?userid="+getUserID()+"'>"+result+"</a>!");`, but that didn't work, I didn't get any result, except for `undefined` (I understand it has something to do with asynchronous AJAX).

This is the content of API.php:

```
case "getUserID":
    echo getUserID();
    break;
```

it call's for function `getUserID()` from file BusinessLogic.php, which has this function:

```
function getUserID()
{
$arr = select("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
return $arr[0]["userID"];
}
```

I've been told that I have to use callbacks, but I have no idea how to do that, how to write this callback. I'm lost here...

Some help, please?

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS with 3 requests. Just deliver the right HTML - you have the log-in-status at the server. No need to do 2 or more API queries on-load.

Comment: I agree about the 3 request, just one but I would return a JSON with the data I need so that the HTML stay on the client side instead of being generated by a server side script.

Comment: @Bergi I'm a beginner, I really don't know how to use what you just told...

Comment: @gillesc Again, I don't really know how to do it... I'm just learning it all, and have to finish this college project in a few days, by using only the techniques we've learned. So I kinda have to use all the calls anyway. But have no idea how to get this user ID as I need...

Comment: No worries. Here some of the problems are that you are using getJSON, which expect valid JSON. The back end code seems to return a single string, so that's even weird you can get a value for the username. jQuery normally expect valid JSON data when using getJSON.
But basically you can return a string with multiple values which is a valid JSON object {"username":"me","id":"1"} and then access it in the callback like such function(data){ alert(data.username + ' id is ' + data.id); }

Comment: @lgal: I mean't: Don't use any javascript for that. Serve all the information in your html. And if you really need to make it dynamic, build an api that allows retrieval of multiple values in 1 request.

Comment: @Bergi excellent point, js might not be needed + 1

Comment: @Bergi I agree, now I see the problem with getting only one value. It was some bad thing for the teacher to teach us. Oh well, I'll be smarter next time, this time I have to work with what I have...

Comment: @gillesc Weel, the single string that I retrieve here is actually the username itself, like that: `if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
  return json_encode($_SESSION["username"]);
 return json_encode(null);` Thank you for your input! I'll try to implement it here, ot maybe in next project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command : "getUserID"}, function(result){
    var id = result;
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command : "getUserName"}, function(result){
         $("#divGreeting").html("Hello, "+result+"!");
         $("#divHeader").html("Hello, <a href='userpage.html?userid="+id+"'>"+result+"</a>!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it now, the link I got eventually looked like that: `userpage.html?userid=[object Object]`

Comment: I've updated the code with the correct sequence of AJAX calls required.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just what I was looking for! Though I'm having some problems with displaying 'Hello guest' when the username == null, but I'll try to figure something out...

Comment: Just put Hello, Guest in the HTML of `#divGreeting`. Then this function can overwrite it with the user's name. That way you can remove the `if..else` statement.

Comment: And don't forget the onload-handler.

Answer (score 0):

The code that uses your ajax response

```
$("#divGreeting").html("Hello, <a href='userpage.html?userid="+getUserID()+"'>"+result+"</a>!");
```

Must be in the callback of the ajax function.

Comment: Again, I have no idea in which callback to use it and how... I thought it's already in the callback the first function (the one that has `command : "getUserName"`...

Answer (score 0):

AJAX queries don't block the execution of a function, so when you call getUserID all it does it initialize the AJAX call and return undefined as no return was set. Adding return like suggested won't work either as all you will do is return something else, jQuery probably.

You have to fetch the id before you can generate anything. So when you ask for the username and you get one instead of displaying thing straight away you do your AJAX call to get the id and then the callback of that render your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using callbacks.

The $.getJSON syntax is:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [callback] )
```

- You have 5 `{` brackets in your code but only 4 `}` brackets. Maybe
  this is the error?
- What do you see if you type
  `yourdomain.com/INC/API.php?command=getUserName` in your browser? If
  the document is empty, the error is in your PHP file, if the username appears, the problem is in your jQuery code.
- You didn't tell us what happens if you execute the javascript code. What does appear? "Hello username", "Hello guest" or nothing?

Comment: Counted the {} brackets - everything seems normal. Also, I work with Dreamweaver, it would've signaled me if I'd happen to miss a bracket. When I typed the URL you've mentioned I got the username of the logged in account, and when I was logged out i got `null`. If I'm logged in it says `Heelo, username` with actual username, not the word username; if I'm logged out it says `Hello guest`.

Comment: Isn't this what you wanted? 
So what is the problem if it works like it should?

Comment: No, not exactly - I needed to make the username to be a link, with userID value. I had troubles with getting the userID...